# Azure IotHub - Newly added routing enpoint (queue) is not available on list

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm using students subscription on Azure platform.
I've menaged to deploy IoTHub and Service Bus with queue.

I want to establish routing from my devices to Service Bus queue. I've added new endpoint (selected name, service bus, queue and accepted) and got notification that endpoint had been added.
However there is no endpoint on list (except earlier blob storage endpoint that is not a matter of this question).

---

Adding endpoint:
[image]

---

Notification:

[image]

---

IotHub enpoints:

[image]

Comment: Hi, if the answer below doesn't help, could you add screenshots of the steps you took and the end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this bug in the past, try to hard refresh (ctrl+F5) or wait some time.If it didn't help try to do the endpoint one more time.

Comment: Not working. Yesterday i've tried many times too. Nothing on the list.

Comment: Tier of IoT hub?

Comment: IotHub pricing: F1 - free

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem with this tier but maybe try to change it to B1.